# The fear of death is very puzzling, in a way that regret about the end of life is not

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The fear of death is very puzzling, in a way that regret about the end
>   of life is not. It's easy to understand that we might want to have
>   more life, more of the things it contains, so that we see death as a
>   negative evil. But how can the prospect of your own nonexistence be
>   alarming in a positive way?

Thomas Nagel , What does it all mean?

I find the expression "in a way that regret about the end of life is not" very difficult to understand. So could you explain this to me?

I tried to rewrite it like this:

> "The fear of death is very difficult to understand, unlike the regret
>   for the end of life"

.

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you got it! :)

Comment: I find the last sentence of the quote very puzzling.